# Why is 10^-8 be different than .1^8?

Tags: vb.net, double, long-integer

In vb.net

In fact, I snip the watch window

[image: enter imagecorrection here]

10^-8 is correct 1e-8

Yet there is something with .1^8 or even .1^2

Why?

For an experiment, I tried with .1*.1 and 1/100 and 1/(10^8). Some produce correct results and some don't. I wonder why.

My guess is 10^-1, which is mathematically equivalent with .1 can be coded **exactly**. They are stored differently than .1. I don't exactly know how. I think they have the same mantisa and then they just have -1 as exponent.

Notice that 10^-120 seems to show up as exact

[image]

Problems only start after 10^-309

10^-308 is still accurate.

I wonder how they represent it? in ieee754

Comment: Is this simply due to the way that floating point numbers are represented?  You notice that VB.Net is telling you that 0.1^2 is actually `0.010000...2`.  That is because it's not possible to store _exactly_ `0.01` in a floating-point number.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html which shows you how actual values are stored in a double-precision floating point number

Comment: But 10^-1 can be represented exactly. How is that?

Comment: 10^-1 can't be represented exactly, but the error is small enough that VS doesn't show it.  10^-8 is a single operation with a single error, whereas 0.1^8 takes the error from the inexact representation of 0.1 and multiplies it eight times, greatly increasing its impact.

Comment: So 10^-8 is also not exact. How do I know how it is represented in IEEE754 then?

Comment: This must be very exact because 10^-309 is when it start being problematic